# What is the best way to load passwords to python code?

Tags: python

I am connecting to API using python, and I'm wondering what is the safest and best practice to load passwords without explicitly add them in code or config files.

Thanks

Comment: Better use a `secrets` file which is not tracked as part of version control and can be shared among your team internally. Be it `json` or `plain text` file. Have it in some specific folder for your project where you can refer to using file system. Load your passwords and other info from that `secrets` file.

Comment: Is there any library I should use to load? or simply file reading ?
Should I encrypt the file? and how?

Comment: any code snippet will help. Thanks

Comment: You could also try setting environment variables. Perhaps this article might be helpful to you. https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/handling-sensitive-keys/

Comment: you can use [Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis) to store sensitive info they also have a [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python)

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is a good way to handle this. I typically use either this or [`python-dotenv`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

I usually keep a copy in version control with no values, and in each environment, duplicate the file and add your sensitive information. For example, you might have `settings.conf.example` in version control with lines like `API_KEY=` (no value) and also any documentation on what needs to be populated, copy that file to `settings.conf` (which should be in your `.gitignore` or comparable file), and fill in the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
What if the application is to be run on client side?
How to deliver the application with the credentials and how to protect the file?
Sorry if the answer is too obvious

Comment: That would depend on the details of how you're distributing it. If you need your script to run on the client but don't trust the client with your secrets, encrypting the file means your script will need the encryption key to read it, which you then also need to hide from the client... in a situation like this, if it's actually necessary both to run on the client and to protect those secrets, I'd probably plan on setting up a web service the script can access that will relay requests to the web service and send the responses back.